# Find a file name within a folder and make it a variable

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I'm trying to run a macro that will take a folder path I've provided and then take the file in that folder and make the file name the variable.  That file name variable will then be used as part of a VLookup to get data from a cell within that file. Below is the code I've found so far, but I haven't been able to make it work:

```
Dim FilePath As String
FilePath = "____________________"

Set wbCodeBook = ThisWorkbook
    With Application.FileSearch
    .NewSearch
    'Change path to suit
    .LookIn = FilePath
    .FileType = msoFileTypeExcelWorkbooks
    'Optional filter with wildcard
    .filename = "*AD*.xlsm*"
    End With
```

I get *Object doesn't support this action* at the `Application.FileSearch` part of the code. I also don't know how I can take that code above and make the output the variable.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this ?

```
Public Function GetFileName() As String
    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim sFileName As String
    '----------------
    sFilePath = "____________________"
    sFileName = "*AD*.xlsm*"
    GetFileName = Dir(sFilePath & sFileName, vbNormal)
End Function
```

If you put it a module, you can then call it in a cell using =GetFileName().

Comment: Thanks. This looks like it will work better than what I had. The only issue I'm having is that it is recognizing the file name as "". In most cases, the referenced folder will only have one file in it; however there might be some instances where there is two files. The differentiation between them is that the file I'm looking to get the data from has "AD" in the middle of the file name, while the other one would not. I would think that have the asterisk before and after AD would allow this to work, but it did not in this case.

Comment: I'm surprised as the wildcard * works well on my side. If it doesn't work, you'll have to loop and test the output filenames with operator `Like`.